# c# for WP7.5: How to do remote backup of a .txt file?

Tags: windows-phone-7, backup

I want to complete my application with a function that automatically downloads or uploads three .txt files, which are generated by my application. How to do it? Can I do it with one of my web sites? How? Which functions should I use?

What i would to do is similar than EverNote, so I know what i want to do is possible in C#.

Answer (score 0):

i would assume that you have a server for your website.
you could use the server as the endpoint and send it over via a stream or create your own set of api.

Comment: Wait a moment: my website is geheimerschatz.altervista.org and i do not know if i can create what you are saying. I am not paying for a website...

Comment: from your description, it would seem to be a no.
and it seem that there will lots of upload given that txt is generated from the application. it would also be better to storage them properly for easy retrieving

Comment: :( Nooo. I please you. Make me see the light!! Mine is a free project, that i would to port to different OS

Answer (score 0):

[SkyDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826550.aspx) and [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) both support uploads and downloads from Windows Phone, and are available on iOS and Android as well.